# Is the core CLR of Silverlight 4 the same as 'classic' .Net 4?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I ask this because I have been chasing down a co/contravariance issue in SL4. I asked it twice in SO and got answers along the lines of - "It just works, make sure you are using .net 4". I tried my failing code (and the samples people posted) in SL4 and .Net 4 and the results are different (work in .net fail in sl). So is SL4 actually running on a < 4 version. Or are there just some features left out (accidentally or on purpose). If so what features

What about SL 5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core compiler in Silverlight 4 supports Covariance and Contravariance, but the framework interfaces (ie: [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)) unfortunately were not marked as covariant (note in the docs that it isn't `IEnumerable<out T>` as it is in .NET 4).

[Silverlight 5 fixes this](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/09/04/the-big-list-of-whats-new-or-improved-in-silverlight-5), "officially" supporting Covariance and Contravariance.